# Show message single time only

Tags: android, arrays, loops

I want to show unsuccessful message single time but it prints every time..

```
for (String[] s : array) {
    if (s[0].equals(edtUsername.getText().toString()) && s[1].equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;

    } else { 

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UnSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: which message prints all the time?

Comment: Unsuccessful.. when the login credentials are incorrect..

Comment: You are not showing us the context: this verification loop could be called from any place any number of times, not to mention that we know nothing about what's in the `array`. Edit: judging by the answers, it may also be that you are checking user's input against values in the array. In this case your `else` is in the wrong place. Just place it AFTER the loop so that it only reports `UnSuccess` once after all the checks had failed.

Comment: How can i place the else body after the for loop..? when the IF statement is actually in the for loop..? Won't it raise an error ..?

Comment: After the loop there's simply no `else` since the successful match will exit the function anyway. So whatever executes after the if is code that only executes if NONE of the items compared to user credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the `UnSuccess` toast message only one time then you have to place it outside the `for-loof` as below...

```
for (String[] s : array) {

    if (s[0].equals(edtUsername.getText().toString())
                                    && s[1].equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;

    }
}

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UnSuccess",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: if i add return in the else the loop will break and it will never check second index of a two dimensional array..